# Google Map Api Options - Not registering

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have tried to add options to my google map based on this page:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions

However, only the draggle:false one works! You can still double click and the UI is still there.

```
 function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.8688, 151.2195),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    draggable:false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom:false,
    disableDefaultUI:false,
    keyboardShortcuts:false,
    };
```

**Link to code:**
http://jsfiddle.net/qcPgL/4/

Where have I gone wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

disable false is the default behavior.  Try

```
disableDoubleClickZoom:true,
disableDefaultUI:true,
keyboardShortcuts:true,
```

See the example in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#DisablingDefaults)